# 404 Not Found for file link at Yii2 app-advanced with one-domain configuration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

I have one-domain configuration at my yii2 app-advanced project. Before config works fine, but now I couldn't manage link to any image file. When I tried to download file by `http://{domain}/icons/logo.svg` link, I have 404 error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /icons/logo.svg was not found on this server.
```

But `http://{domain}/frontend/web/icons/logo.svg` works. **File exist in showed folder**. How to correct apache config files at project to use short links.

*Here my config:*

- apache:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName test.dev

       ServerAdmin test@test.ua
       DocumentRoot /home/user/Projects/test-app/

       <Directory /home/user/Projects/test-app/>
           Require all granted
           AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- base `.htacces`:

  ```
  Options -Indexes
  IndexIgnore */*

  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteRule ^admin(.{2,})?(/)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
  RewriteRule ^([^/].*)?$ /frontend/web/$1
  </IfModule>
  ```
- frontend `.htacces`:

  ```
  Options -Indexes

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
  </IfModule>

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  ```

  - also enabled in config file `frontend\config\main.php`:

```php
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'site/index',
            'sitemap' => 'sitemap/index',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
Apache have own directory `icons` for it own icons. And this alias can be overwritten only on server configuration at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf`

Issue described here: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/apache-icons-directory/

So, if you want use icons folder name, you should put it at subdirecotory, for example `img/icons/...`. Or use another directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^icons/(.*)$ frontend/web/icons/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sardor Dushamov, your variant not work too.
Beside, described at question configuration works fine in other yii2 projects on my PC. Maybe, some error is more general?